# gnupg: Getting errors trying to gpg --gen-key

Tags: gpg, gnupg

I have tried deleting my .gnupg directory but the error returns.

I get this:

```
gpg: lookup_hashtable failed: eof
gpg: lookup_hashtable failed: eof
gpg: upd_hashtable: read failed: eof
gpg: trust record 2, type 12: write failed: eof
gpg: Error: The trustdb is corrupted.
gpg: You may try to re-create the trustdb using the commands:
gpg:   cd ~/.gnupg
gpg:   gpg2 --export-ownertrust > otrust.tmp
gpg:   rm trustdb.gpg
gpg:   gpg2 --import-ownertrust < otrust.tmp
gpg: If that does not work, please consult the manual
```

I tried following the advice thrown out by the error and that doesn't work either. Tried Googling the problem but nothing comes up for "lookup_hastable".

I also installed seahorse and have my ssh keys stored in seahorse. Could there be confict going on with seahorse?

I'm running `gpg --gen-key` from my normal user account and not trying to do anything fancy: just create a standard gpg key.

Comment: did you follow the instruction from the error message?

Comment: What version of GnuPG is this? Is there an instance of `gpg-agent` running that is interfering, and that might need to be killed?

Comment: Run `gpg --fix-trustdb`

Comment: I did have gpg-agent running. I killed it and tried to create another key: same problem. Then I deleted my ~/.gnupg directory and it works! I am going to try rebooting to see if gpg-agent comes back to stop me again. Thanks!

Comment: Just rebooted and gpg-agent doesn't start on boot, but curiously only appears once I run seahorse and close it again. Will remember to close gpg-agent before doing key operations in future. (solved)

Comment: `gpg-agent` will automatically start when doing key operations with GnuPG 2.1, as it should do. The problem was either that you're using two different versions of GnuPG at once, or that something else modified the contents of the `.gnupg` directory in such a way that `gpg-agent` got confused. When deleting the `.gnupg` directory, the running `gpg-agent` was unaware of it. That's very much a "hand waving" type of explanation.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334280/gnupg-getting-errors-trying-to-gpg-gen-key#comment588854_334280 what what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue with lookup_hashtable failing due to `Unknown system error` instead.

I figured it happened after importing a private key through gpg (and not gpg2) using `gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import private.key`

After setting trust level following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361068/gnupg-there-is-no-assurance-this-key-belongs-to-the-named-user), the error was gone.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I think as part of commands it is using rm which fails if it is interactive "rm -i"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What is important to realize, is that there are [two main versions](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2016q3/000393.html) of GnuPG ('classic' and 'stable', and also there is a 'modern' `2.1`): `gpg` and `gpg2` (on Fedora Core they are provided by packages `gnupg` and `gnupg2` respectively).

I searched the Internet about `trustdb` extensively, removed `~/.gnupg`, but could find very little information and that did not help.

Since in my OS repository there was an old version of `gpg`, I downloaded a 'modern' `gpg` from the official site. There was a problem with `libgrypt`, I needed to install a newer library version for `gpg` to work. When I did it manually, my system refused to boot at all. I think I'll fix that soon, but now I work from another laptop.

Finally I realized that there is a package `gnupg2` and I used the command `gpg2` instead of `gpg`. That worked flawlessly.
You may set a bash `alias gpg=gpg2` in your `.bash_profile` if you wish to forget about numbers at all.